# Plot Projects - introducing Notification filter to an existing application

Tags: android, ios, notifications, geofencing

I'm using Plot Projects service to send geofencing notifications to users of iOS and Android application. Currently, notifications are not filtered or segmented - i.e. all users are receiving them.

A new type of notifications being introduced to the system should shown only to specific users under certain conditions, and for that purpose the Notification filter would be used.

Of course, since the new notifications are user-specific, the old versions of the applications should not be showing these notifications at all. If they did, users using the apps without the filter would receive all notifications, and be overwhelmed with misplaced notifications.

It seems like the segmentation would be the solution for this. Set up the the new applications so that they register all users within a newly created segment, and thus link all the users to it once they start using the new apps. What confused me is that, when configuring segment on a Notification campaign, the note in Plot Projects dashboard says:

> "Note that this option is only available if you implement segmentation inside your app."

Segmentation is not being used in the old app version, and it seems logical that in this case the users on old app versions will not receive the notifications for segmented campaigns (as expected).

However, the wording seems a bit ambiguous - the old versions of the apps do not have segmentation implemented at all, so does this mean that the segmentation settings will not be applied to them, having them show all notification? Or will segmentation work properly, and have no users of old app versions receive the new segmented notifications?

If the segmentation would be applied properly, then the proposed seems like a proper solution. If not, what would be the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications with segmentation will only be sent to a device where the segmentation property is set to a matching value. So if a segmentation property is not set (eg. in a previous version of your app) or set to a non-matching value the notification is not sent to that device.

Using segmentation to make sure that notifiations are only sent to certain versions of your app seems like the way to go. There is however one pitfall: you cannot exclude the new app version for current notifications. Segmentation operators like "is equal to" or "is not equal to" will only work if the segmentation property is set in the app. Since it is not set in the old version of the app you cannot use segmentation for those notifications. The solution is to design the Notification Filter in such a way that it can detect the notifications for the old app version and not let them pass. In the future we might add a segmentation operator like "is not set" but for now this is the only way to make sure new app versions will not send the old notifications.

I agree that the warning in the dashboard might give the wrong understanding about how segmentation works. We will look into improving this message. Thanks for your feedback!